# Overwriting parent component

Tags: angular

I'm developing a frontend with Angular 9. The entire application has a header and sidebar, but the main application should be shielded from the public, so behind a login page.

The problem I'm having is that the login page shouldn't have the header and sidebar that every other page has, so I want that page to not include them. How can I do that?

Comment: Why would the Login page automatically have the header, if you don't specify it ? Could you show a minimal example reproducing your problem on stackblitz for instance ? (with some of the relevant code in the qeustion itself ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a login page and when login is successfully go to the home page with has a header selector , router-outlet (for your child routes), footer selector.

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```
                                        +--------------------------------+
                                        ||      HeaderComponent         ||
 +---------------+                      ||                              ||
 |               |      Routing to      |--------------------------------+
 |               |     MainComponent    ||    |                          |
 |LoginComponent +--------------------> ||Side|                          |
 |               |                      ||Nav |                          |
 |               |                      ||    |            MainComponent |
 +---------------+                      ||    |                          |
                                        ||    |                          |
                                        ||    |                          |
                                        ||    |                          |
                                        +--------------------------------+
```